# .htaccess but still accessible?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I installed Wordpress on my Apache webserver and putted the htaccess file (below) in the admin folder. It look likes this works when i test trying to access the admin pages with a 'strange' ip -> i'm blocked.
The strange thing about this is that i can still see invalid logins on my admin pages (ithemes security) and i see these ip addresses also in my server access log accessing those admin pages.

Anybody any idea how this is possible and how i can block all these ip addressed up front?

Thanks.

```
order deny,allow
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
deny from all


<FilesMatch "^\.">
Order allow,deny
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Login attemps came from wp-login file on the root. Also managed this with a htaccess and it's solved now.